# How to add one more leave to my tree graph?

Tags: graphs, trees

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.X leaf_1 [.Y leaf_2 [.Z leaf_3 last !{\qbalance} ] ] ]
\end{document}
```

I would like to add one more leave and node under leaf_1.How can i do it?

Another question how can i write a text paralel to graph leave?

Is it possible to have frame around nodes, like a circle node?

[image: I am trying to create something like this]

I am trying to create something like this

Edit 2:I tried to modified this by removing student node and all leaves that linked to it but I got an error here is my code,

```
\begin{forest}
  shade me/.style={%
    bottom color=#1!25,
    top color=#1!5,
    draw=#1,
    drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  my label/.style n args=2{%
    edge label={node [midway, black, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1] {#2}}
  },
  where n children=0{%
    shade me=blue!50!cyan,
  }{%
    if level=0{%
      shade me=green!75!gray,
    }{%
      shade me=blue!75!magenta,
    }
  },
  for tree={%
    delay={content/.wrap value={\strut #1}},
    edge={red,->},
    l sep+=25pt,
    s sep+=20pt
  }
  [Debt
  [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
      [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
    ]

    [CR, my label={above, sloped}{Low}
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
      [Age, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]]
      ]
    ]

\end{forest}
```

Comment: Please give us some compilable code. We do not want to guess, what packages are needed in order to compile this. Thank you. And welcome to our site!

Comment: Sorry, here is the package \usepackage{qtree} and above the single code line works by it self

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example we can copy-paste-compile. It should begin `\documentclass` and end `\end{document}` if you are using LaTeX.

Comment: For the fancier result, I would recommend using a different package - either TikZ-based or pstricks-based, depending on which you prefer. For TikZ,  `tikz-qtree` has similar syntax although I find Forest's syntax much more intuitive.

Comment: Please ask one question only, if you have two related questions check whether than can be combined á la "How can this be done in TeX" (usually not the most popular questions). Or split it into two questions. This way it is assured that your questions and the answers are searchable (findable) and other can benefit from them

Comment: Please roll back your edit. As it stands, your other question is a duplicate of this one. But I've answered that question there not here. And my answer here doesn't address the current version of this question. But this question won't make sense if I delete my answer because there won't be an answer for you to have modified.

Comment: I agree the current question is unclear. The original was clear enough. It was 2 questions, maybe, but it was not unclear. So I can see why people want to close this as unclear, even though I answered the 2 original clear questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want this?

[image: additional leaf and node]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qtree}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.X [.leaf_1 leaf_4 node ] [.Y leaf_2 [.Z leaf_3 last !{\qbalance} ] ] ]
\end{document}
```

For the fancier tree, you will need a fancier package. Here's an example using Forest:

[image: fancier tree]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  shade me/.style={%
    bottom color=#1!25,
    top color=#1!5,
    draw=#1,
    drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  my label/.style n args=2{%
    edge label={node [midway, black, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1] {#2}}
  },
  where n children=0{%
    shade me=blue!50!cyan,
  }{%
    if level=0{%
      shade me=green!75!gray,
    }{%
      shade me=blue!75!magenta,
    }
  },
  for tree={%
    delay={content/.wrap value={\strut #1}},
    edge={red,->},
    l sep+=25pt,
    s sep+=20pt
  }
  [Income
  [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
      [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
    ]
    [Student, my label={}{Medium}
      [Age
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
        [CR, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}
          [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
          [No, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}]
        ]
      ]
      [Yes]
    ]
    [CR, my label={above, sloped}{Low}
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
      [Age, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried to delete student node and leaves linked to it. but it didnt work. I have added my code in my first message

Comment: Don't leave a blank line within the tree. That will cause errors. Is that what you mean by 'didn't work'?