# How to edit forest tree?

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

Here is the sample latex code i found for drawing tree

```
    \begin{forest}   shade me/.style={%
        bottom color=#1!25,
        top color=#1!5,
        draw=#1,
        drop shadow,
        font=\sffamily,   },   my label/.style n args=2{%
        edge label={node [midway, black, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1] {#2}}   },   where n children=0{%
        shade me=blue!50!cyan,   }{%
        if level=0{%
          shade me=green!75!gray,
        }{%
          shade me=blue!75!magenta,
        }   },   for tree={%
        delay={content/.wrap value={\strut #1}},
        edge={red,->},
        l sep+=25pt,
        s sep+=20pt   }   [Income  

 [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
          [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
          [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
        ]
        [Student, my label={}{Medium}
          [Age
            [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
            [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
            [CR, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}
              [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
              [No, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}]
            ]
          ]
          [Yes]
        ]
        [CR, my label={above, sloped}{Low}
          [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
          [Age, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}
            [No, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}]
            [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]]
          ]
        ]   ] \end{forest}
```

However when I try to modify it, it didnt work,I thought to remove student node and all leaves linked it, I can just remove this code and it will be ok,but it wasnt.I have checked the brackets and parentheses they are all closed.

```
[Student, my label={}{Medium}
      [Age
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
        [CR, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}
          [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
          [No, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}]
        ]
      ]
      [Yes]
    ]
```

Other thing I wanted to change to delete node yes which is under age node and leave just node "no".  So I have removed this line but it didnt help.

```
[Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
```

Comment: Could you please make your code compilable? Thanks.

Comment: Please link to the place where you found the code.

Comment: [I already said that you must remove blank lines from the tree specification.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307631/how-to-add-one-more-leave-to-my-tree-graph/307637#comment747595_307637)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307631/how-to-add-one-more-leave-to-my-tree-graph/307637#307637.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the student node and those linked to it, you just need to remove the relevant lines of code from the tree specification. However, ***you must not leave blank lines within the `forest` environment***.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  shade me/.style={%
    bottom color=#1!25,
    top color=#1!5,
    draw=#1,
    drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  my label/.style n args=2{%
    edge label={node [midway, black, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1] {#2}}
  },
  where n children=0{%
    shade me=blue!50!cyan,
  }{%
    if level=0{%
      shade me=green!75!gray,
    }{%
      shade me=blue!75!magenta,
    }
  },
  for tree={%
    delay={content/.wrap value={\strut #1}},
    edge={red,->},
    l sep+=25pt,
    s sep+=20pt
  }
  [Income
  [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
      [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]
    ]
    [CR, my label={above, sloped}{Low}
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
      [Age, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: pruned tree]

Similarly, to remove the `Yes` node under the main `Age` node on the left, for example, you can just remove the line.

```
\begin{forest}
  shade me/.style={%
    bottom color=#1!25,
    top color=#1!5,
    draw=#1,
    drop shadow,
    font=\sffamily,
  },
  my label/.style n args=2{%
    edge label={node [midway, black, font=\sffamily\scriptsize, #1] {#2}}
  },
  where n children=0{%
    shade me=blue!50!cyan,
  }{%
    if level=0{%
      shade me=green!75!gray,
    }{%
      shade me=blue!75!magenta,
    }
  },
  for tree={%
    delay={content/.wrap value={\strut #1}},
    edge={red,->},
    l sep+=25pt,
    s sep+=20pt
  }
  [Income
    [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
      [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
    ]
    [CR, my label={above, sloped}{Low}
      [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{Fair}]
      [Age, my label={above, sloped}{Excellent}
        [No, my label={above, sloped}{$> 40$}]
        [Yes, my label={above, sloped}{$31\dots 40$}]]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

[image: further pruning]

If you want the regular direction, even though there's only one child, rather than the `No` directly below `Age`, you can use a `phantom` node. For example,

```
  [Income
    [Age, my label={above, sloped}{High}
      [No, my label={above, sloped}{$< 30$}]
      [, phantom]
    ]
```

[image: with phantom]